# How to plot time Data

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, plot, time

My data structure looks like this:

[image: Data]

Now I want to select 3 cities and plot them over time (x=Date, y=Amount). Additionally, I want the months to be on the x-axis every 3 months.

I tried ggplot, but it seems that my date is not defined correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make data frame:

```
> city <- c('Berlin', 'Munchen', 'Koln', 'Hamburg', 'Dusseldorf', 'Frankfurt am Main', 'Leipzig')
> Date <- c('2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-01', '2015-01')
> AMount <- c(3740, 1282, 948, 946, 947, 302, 227)
> df <- data.frame(city, Date, AMount)
> df
```

```
               city    Date AMount
1            Berlin 2015-01   3740
2           Munchen 2015-01   1282
3              Koln 2015-01    948
4           Hamburg 2015-01    946
5        Dusseldorf 2015-01    947
6 Frankfurt am Main 2015-01    302
7           Leipzig 2015-01    227
```

Convert the **Date** to Year and Month.

```
> library(zoo)
> df$Date <- as.yearmon(df$Date)
> df
```

```
               city     Date AMount
1            Berlin Jan 2015   3740
2           Munchen Jan 2015   1282
3              Koln Jan 2015    948
4           Hamburg Jan 2015    946
5        Dusseldorf Jan 2015    947
6 Frankfurt am Main Jan 2015    302
7           Leipzig Jan 2015    227
```

Plotting with ggplot

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(df[1:3,], aes(x=as.Date(Date),y=AMount)) + geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y")
```

%b = Abreviated month name, for example **Jan** for **January**